# ASP.NET Entity Framework making Quiz

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am new with Web and really stuck. I need to make QuizSystem using ASP.NET and Entity Framework. I use databse first and I have such Tables

[image: Qustion Table]

And

[image: Variant Table]

I'm trying to make Create View for Question, but problem is Question use some already made Variant as answer and I need just pick it from drop down list.

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Text,AnswerID,ChapterID")] QuestionVariant questionVariant)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.QuestionVariants.Add(questionVariant);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.ChapterID = new SelectList(db.Chapters, "ChapterID", "ChapterName", questionVariant.ChapterID);
        ViewBag.AnswerID = new SelectList(db.Variants, "VariantID", "Text", questionVariant.AnswerID);
        return View(questionVariant);
    }
```

Is it possible to create questions and variants in same view? And if so how controller and view should look? Dont put just -1, help me with some advises or anything that would help to solve this problem.

Comment: QuestionVariants means answers of question?

Comment: @Nico yes possible answers of question

Comment: What are you asking? Of course you can put them in the same view... You have showed your POST method handler which is where your view will send?

Comment: ViewModels are your friend here. Create a separate class (viewmodel) and include the fields (from whatever sources) you want to display including the DropDownList values. Example [here](http://sampathloku.blogspot.com/2012/10/how-to-use-viewmodel-with-aspnet-mvc.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think your table design need some adjustment. try to change your Question model.AnswerId to=>

```
public virtual ICollection<QuestionVariants> QuestionVariants{ get; set; }
```

Add Question property to QuestionVariant and apply ForeignKey attribute to that.

```
[ForeignKey("QuestionId")]    
public Question Question { get; set; }
```

In addition you can read 'ForeignKey' and 'One to Many' Section of [this tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx).